# chrome.storage.sync.get() default object sorted contrary to JS convention?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, javascript-objects

Per [Mathias Bynens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/96656/mathias-bynens) highly upvoted answer to ["Sort JavaScript object by key"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467129/sort-javascript-object-by-key/31102605#31102605), string keys in JS objects will be sorted in the order in which they were entered, eg when retrieved by `Object.keys()`. This indeed also happens when I try it in an ordinary fashion. However, when using a string-key object as parameter `key` in the Chrome extension API call  `chrome.storage.sync.get(key,function(retrieved_data){})`, the result, in my hands, is an object where the keys obtained by `Object.keys()` are sorted alphabetically and not in the order they were entered.
I use the `key` parameter to store default values (most often for option settings in an extension) which can be used as a fallback when the extension fails to retrieve any data from storage (typically the first time an extension is used). The example below shows the difference in behaviour.

**manifest.json:**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2, 
  "name": "demo extension",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "debugging tool",
   "permissions":[
    "storage"
  ],
 "content_scripts": [{
       "css": ["styles.css"], 
      "js": ["jquery.js","content.js"],
    "matches": ["https://*.google.com/*"]
  }]
}
```

**styles.css:**

```
.myTxt{height:100px;,width:150px;}
```

**content.js** (jQuery also required):

```
jQuery(function($){
  var keys;
  var fallbackObject = {z:"first",a:"last"};
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").prepend(`<textarea id="myTxt1" class="myTxt"></textarea><textarea id="myTxt2" class="myTxt"></textarea>`);
    
    //===== alternative 1:  ============
    //fallbackObject is used "normally"
    keys = Object.keys(fallbackObject);
    $("#myTxt1").val("Alternative 1, without chrome.storage.sync.get(): " + keys);
    //result : "z,a"
    
    //===== alternative 2:  ============
    //fallbackObject is used as a default parameter in chrome.storage.sync.get();
    
    chrome.storage.sync.get({storageObject:fallbackObject},function(message){
      keys = Object.keys(message.storageObject);
      $("#myTxt2").val("Alternative 2, with chrome.storage.sync.get(): " + keys);
    });
    //result:"a,z"
 });
});
```

**result:**
[image: result of demo code]

Is this an intended behaviour or maybe a bug in the chrome.storage API?

Comment: Maybe Chrome's storage does not use JS Objects nor JSON internally, in which case, this order can be lost in the process of storing values, and getting them back

Comment: Storage is using JSON schema so it doesn't guarantee the order of object keys.

Comment: Would that be true regardless of StorageArea, ie also for `chrome.storage.local`? Either way, I think it certainly would be an improvement if key order could be preserved also in this context. I solved the problem by using an array of objects instead to make sure the order is unchanged.